# Find limits of double integral for both cases

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$\textbf{Theory}$

It is well known that there's:

$$\iint\limits_D f(x,y)\ dx\space dy$$

expanding it we have:

$$\int_a^b dx \int_{y_1}^{y_2} f(x,y)\,dy = \int_a^b dy \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x,y)\, dx$$

$\textbf{Practice}$

I want to understand the idea, so there will be just simple example

I have a triangle with dots:

$O(0,0)$ $A(2,1)$ $B(-2,1)$

Plotting this:

[image]

So it is very well seen that limits for $\int dx$ are $[-2;2]$ and for $\int dy$ are $[0;1]$

but how should I determine appropriate functions from the triangle to fill function limits?

Comment: Well, no: when you interchange the integration limits you don't *usually* get the same limits $\;a,\,b\;$ for the first integral...And no: in your example the limits for $\;y\;$ are **not** as you give them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that in the example you gave, we have

$$\int_{-2}^0\int_{-\frac x2}^1 f(x,y)\,dy\,dx+\int_0^2\int_{\frac x2}^1 f(x,y)\,dy\,dx=\int_0^1\int_{-2y}^{2y}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$

Comment: as I can judge it is also possible to write $x = |y|/2$

Comment: @M.Mass Where? You still have to subdivide, in the left case, in two double integrals as the limits for $\;x\;$ are different. This is an *irregular* integration domain and as such, just as with simple integrals, we have to divide the domain to convert it in several simple ones.